# Redux Saga call api before token is set

Tags: reactjs, redux, keycloak, redux-saga

I m trying to implements a react application with authentification using keycloak, all sounds good but when I refresh the page and there is fetching of an api, Saga perform the call before the token is set

there is my saga call

```
function* getAPI(action) {
    const state = yield select();
    try {
        let response = yield call(
            axiosRequest,
            "get",
            BaseURL,
            `/foo/mini`,
            {},
            setAuthorizationBearer(state.auth.token),
            { sendToken: true },
            "application/json"
        );
        yield put({ type: `${action.type}_SUCCESS`, payload: response, metadata: action.metadata })
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({ type: `${action.type}_ERROR`, payload: e })
    }
}
```

and here is my axios request instance

```
import axios from "axios";
let authorizationBearer = null;

export const setAuthorizationBearer = token => {
  authorizationBearer = token;
};

const instance = (
  method,
  baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT,
  url,
  data = null,
  headers = null,
  sendToken = true,
  contentType
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const p = {
      sendToken: sendToken.sendToken,
      data: {
        ...data,
      },
    };

    const req = axios.create({
      method,
      baseURL,
      url,
      timeout: 30000,
      headers: headers,
      crossDomain: true,
    });
    headers = {};
    if (p.sendToken && authorizationBearer) {
      headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authorizationBearer}`;
      headers["Content-Type"] = contentType;
    }
    req({
      method,
      baseURL,
      url,
      data,
      headers,
      sendToken,
    })
      .then((payload) => {
        if (payload) {
          if (payload.status < 400) {
            resolve(payload);
          } else {
            reject(payload);
          }
        } else {
          reject(payload);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        if (axios.isCancel(e)) {
          console.log("Request canceled", e.message);
        } else {
          // handle error
        }
        reject(e);
      });
  });
};



export default instance;
```

And finally i set my token on authentification with a dispatch

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

<ReactKeycloakProvider onTokens={({token}) => dispatch(authUser(token))} authClient={Keycloak(config)}
        initOptions={{
          onLoad: 'login-required',
          checkLoginIframe: false,
          timeSkew: "0",
          refreshToken: ""
        }}
        LoadingComponent={<div />}
      >
....
</ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the application content is being rendered before the `onTokens` is being executed. Try checking on the existence of the token in the store state before rendering anything (or show a loading screen).